# Hibernate, JPA cant delete one-to-many relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have one-to-many relation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "login", nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
    private Role role;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Contacts> contacts = new HashSet<Contacts>();
```

And I'm trying to delete `User` object with all Contacts; I tried to use:

1. `cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL`
2. `cascade =
       javax.persistence.CascadeType.REMOVE`
3. `@Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE)` from `org.hibernate.annotations`
4. `@Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)` from `org.hibernate.annotations`

but nothing helped. I always get exception:

> org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Cannot delete or update a
>   parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`contactmanager`.`contact`, CONSTRAINT `contact_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`user_id`) REFERENCES

**UPD**
Code that deletes a User is as follows:

```
@Transactional
public void removeUser(User user) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(user);
}
```

I'll appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting `orphanRemoval = true` on the `OneToMany` relationship? Also, how are you trying to delete the records?

Comment: Yes I've. But for some reason Maven told me:'The attribute orphanRemoval is undefined for the annotation type OneToMany'.

Comment: `orphanRemoval` was introduced in JPA 2.0, so if you're using an older version that would explain why it's undefined. `orphanRemoval` always works for me on similar relationships (using eclipselink). It sounds like `CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN` is a Hibernate-specific (and deprecated) equivalent to `orphanRemoval`, so I'm not sure why it isn't working for you. One last thought is to make sure you have `equals` and `hashCode` [properly defined](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode).

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation here would be to do the relationship management yourself. Cascading removes can be tricky (especially in a situation like yours where the owner of your bi-directional relationship is not the one declaring the cascade) and often times quite dangerous so I usually prefer to avoid them. Especially if you are running a version of JPA pre-2.0 then you don't have too much of a choice. I would just change the removal method to something like:

```
@Transactional
public void removeUser(User user) {
    Set<Contacts> contacts = user.getContacts();

    for (Contact contact : contacts) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(contact);
    }

    contacts.clear();
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(user);
}
```